# Deployment problems on Weblogic server

Tags: spring-mvc, deployment, weblogic, slf4j, weblogic12c

I have two applications, both developed in Spring MVC. One, i.e. VDM is getting deployed and starting just fine in both the local and the live weblogic 12c server. But the other one, i.e. VPORTAL is getting deployed but not starting in the live server. While starting the services, it is giving the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

Interestingly, it is working perfectly in the local server.

I have made some jars consistent in both the applications but it didn't help.
One thing that can be noted is that there was a file namely **log4j.xml** in the VDM's classes directory, but there wasn't any in the VPORTAL. I put it into the VPORTAL after making the changes but it didn't help either.
Please help!

Comment: Kindly include your log4j.xml code

Comment: The one getting error is deployed successfully in local or not.

Comment: Yes it is getting deployed and is starting successfully in the local weblogic 12c. It is getting deployed in the live server but when I start its request services, it comes up with the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a jar version mismatch issue. You do not mention what version of slf4j-api jar you placed under your WEB-INF\lib folder. I suspect it is a different version than the one in WLS 12c. WLS 12.1.1 comes with **org.slf4j.api_1.6.1.0.jar** in its module directory. So what you need to do is add the below section in your **weblogic.xml**, instructing weblogic to load the classes from the **slf4j-api _x.x.x.jar** in your WEB-INF/lib, instead from the **org.slf4j.api_1.6.1.0.jar** from the WLS installation. By default, **org.slf4j.api_1.6.1.0.jar** is used since it is in the server classpath.

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.logging.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: You probably do not need to add the <package-name>org.apache.commons.logging.*</package-name>. Try both ways, with and without.

Comment: I didn't add these descriptors in the VDM app but that is working just fine, moreover the api's are consistent in both VDM and VPORTAL.

Comment: The VDM has the same org.slf4j.api_x.x.x.jar in the WEB-INF/lib? Is it used? Please just add the section in your VPORTAL to see if it works. There could be configuration difference between the two that we do not know.

Comment: No it didn't work. :( yes the VDM has the same jar in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced similar problem with our application.
Application - Spring MVC & we are migrating to Weblogic12c. We tried different way, like modifying pom.xml & all. But finally this change in weblogic.xml helped us.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root>
<wls:session-descriptor>
    <wls:cookie-secure>false</wls:cookie-secure>
    <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>true</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
</wls:session-descriptor>
<wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.xerces</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

---

Pom.xml File:-

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
        <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cactus</groupId>
        <artifactId>
            cactus.core.framework.uberjar.javaEE.14
        </artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cactus</groupId>
        <artifactId>cactus.integration.ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>cactus.integration.shared.api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.cactus</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>onlinesupport-Mysp</groupId>
        <artifactId>coherence</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-chain</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-chain</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-beta-6</version>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cedarsoft.serialization</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jsptags</groupId>
      <artifactId>pager-taglib</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Remove this for Weblogic -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oro</groupId>
        <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>servletapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apple.corp</groupId>
        <artifactId>BlackWord</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apple.corp</groupId>
        <artifactId>AESCryptoAlgorithm</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Quartz framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0_rc9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all-1.0-jsr</artifactId>
            <version>05</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.apple.ist.gcrm.infra.log</groupId>
          <artifactId>cslogger</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>apache-log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
       </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apple.ist.ets</groupId>
        <artifactId>geneva-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>antisamy</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to split up the configuration which Lan mentioned, into two files:

The first one is META-INF/weblogic-application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">

  <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.apache.commons.logging.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>

</weblogic-application>
```

The second one is WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
                                      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.1/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

That way you can force WebLogic (12c in my case) to load your webapp bundled version (must be placed in WEB-INF/lib) of SLF4J first. But it seems, that still both Bindings are available.
German Source: [http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/jee-oracleweblogic.htm#Kompatibilitätsprobleme](http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/jee-oracleweblogic.htm#Kompatibilit%C3%A4tsprobleme)

Comment: 2nd one is not needed

Comment: as far as I remermber, you do actually need it, if you whant to use the dependency in the war archive too.